# InStr search and commas in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of column of rows that contain text such as:

```
dog,cat,mouse
bat,dog,fly
fish,beaver,horse
```

I'm trying to search and highlight rows that contain certain word:

```
Public Sub MarkDuplicates()
Dim iWarnColor As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngCell As Variant
Dim LR As Long
Dim vVal
Dim tRow


LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("B1:B" & LR)
iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccent2

For Each rngCell In rng.Cells
    tRow = rngCell.Row
    If InStr(rngCell.Value, "dog") = 1 Then
        rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor

    Else
        rngCell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

This works fine so long as the word 'dog' is the first word in the comma string, so it would highlight the first row but not row two because the word 'dog' appears after 'bat'. Do I need to strip the commas out first or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried `.Find`? http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/ Looping through every row in a column will be very slow in case you have large amount of rows. When using `.Find` use `LookAt:=xlPart`

Comment: You can also use Autofilter to achieve what you want.

Comment: or simply use comparison like this `If InStr(1,rngCell.Value, "dog") <>0 then`... Additionally, check parameters of `InStr` function.

Comment: @keeg: if you have an option not to use VBA then I highly recommend :@PowerUser's way! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your ultimate goal is to color the row based on whether or not 'dog' is in a cell. Here's a different way to do it that doesn't even involve VBA (this example assumes your data is all in column A):

1. Make a new column to the right. Use the formula `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("dog",A1))),1,0)`. You can hide the column later so the user doesn't see it.  Basically, if it has the word 'dog' somewhere, then return 1 else 0.
2. Select the entire first row
3. Under **Conditional Formatting**, go to **New Rule**
4. Choose **Use a Formula**
5. For your formula, try `=$B2=1`
6. Now that you've conditionally colored one row, copy and **paste format** to the other rows.

All rows should now update automatically.

Extra Credit: If this data is formatted as a table object, the conditional formatting should automatically carry over to new rows as they are added.

Comment: BTW you don't need an additional column :) You can set the conditional formatting in the same column as the data and set the formula there :)

Answer (score 3):

Further to my comments above

**Example 1** (Using `.Find` and `.Findnext`)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MarkDuplicates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iWarnColor As Integer
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim LR As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccent2

    With ws
        LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("B1:B" & LR)

        rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

        Set aCell = rng.Find(What:="dog", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell
            aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
            Do
                Set aCell = rng.FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                    aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Example 2** (Using Autofilter)

For this ensure that there is a Heading in Cell `B1`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MarkDuplicates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iWarnColor As Integer
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim LR As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccent2

    With ws

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("B1:B" & LR)

        With rng
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*dog*"
            Set aCell = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```